# Await for complete asynchronously composed function execution before taking another request

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have a PDF document under rendering with a constraint that [I can open only one page at a time](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-29/blob/master/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.java#L228). I bump several widgets in the `ListView.builder`, which are asking a component which encapsulates the opened PDF document to render the page, returning an image of this PDF page. So I have, for instance. 7 "parallel" (in the common sense of the word) rendering requests that code to the document. What I need is to order them, and it would be convenient to user RX for this.

Generally, I imagine the implementation like this:

```
Observable<RenderingRequest> _requests = ...;

Component() {
    _requests.someMagicOperatorThatSuspendTheFurtherEmissionUntilProcessingIsComplete(_processItem);
}

Future<void> _processItem(RenderingRequest request) {
    final Page page = await _document.openPage(request.index);
    final Image image = await _convertToImage(page);
    await page.close();
    // send processed image through a sink to a subscriber that awaits this particular image, for instance
}
```

But how to actually throttle other requests' processing until the one that is currently registered completes? Is it even possible?

Comment: The `MagicOperatorThat....` is acquiring a [semaphore](https://pub.dev/packages/semaphore)

Comment: Did not thought about them not in the concurrent, but only asynchronous context. Thanks, that should work OK